# Can't connect to new vhost on xampp. Other vhosts working properly

Tags: windows, xampp, hosts

As title says: I've set new vhost in xampp same way I do it allways (code at the end of question). I've set new redirect in `hosts` file. Trying to open page in browser results with "Can't connect" error (like there was no host at all) while `ping` has `timeout` for each query. Other vhosts are working properly. What can be wrong?

**httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@mydomain.dev
    DocumentRoot "D:/proper/path"
    ServerName mydomain.dev
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.dev
    ErrorLog "logs/mydomain.dev.log"
    CustomLog "logs/mydomain.dev.log" common
    <Directory "D:/proper/path">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**hosts**

```
120.0.0.1       mydomain.dev
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was really easy to fix, but hard to notice if you didn't know what could cause such behaviour. What I had wrong was my `hosts` entry:

```
#original:
120.0.0.1       mydomain.dev

#working:
127.0.0.1       mydomain.dev
```

Difference is just one cipher, but that was enough to crash.